# C struct inside a struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a typedef structure which defines an element in a queue. Inside the definition I have another typedef structure with its own values.

```
typedef struct q_elem_s
{
    def_task task;
    int arrive_time;
    struct q_elem_s *next;
} q_elem;
```

Inside q_elem_s is def_task task defined by:

```
typedef struct task_s
{
    int id;
    int length;
} def_task;
```

When I want to access a value inside def_task task I get following error:

"invalid type argument of '->' (have 'def_task')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the actual code; where is struct task_s defined.

Comment: Show your "accessing" code...

Comment: elem->task->id = id; is one example. elem is an instance of q_elem

Comment: task isn't a pointer so putting `->` after it doesn't make sense. You want its id field so express that: elem->task.id (or `(*elem).task.id`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `q_elem` and you want to access `id` from its task you'd use `task.id`. Note that you don't have a `def_task` pointer (`def_task*`), which would need an arrow but rather a `def_task` value. Try doing something like so:

```
q_elem q;
q.task.id = 12;
```

Comment: Now I get "request for member 'task' in something not a structure or union'. What is the difference between using a pointer to the task structure and a task value?

Comment: Alright, I got it. q->elem.id works apparently. Why do I need to dereference the task structure?

Comment: @Pulz Your expression and question makes no sense. There's no dereferencing of a task structure there ... that isn't even coherent, as only pointers are dereferenced. What you want is q->task.id, which dereferences a pointer to a q_elem and then accesses the id member of the task member. Note that equivalent is `(*q).task.id` -- the `*` does dereferencing, and there's only one there.

Answer (score 3):

Both `->` and `.` operator are used to access structure fields. The main difference is that `->` is used when you have a *pointer to a structure* variable and `.` is used when you have a *structure variable*. For example:

```
q_elem* q;   /* q stores the address to a q_elem structure */
q_elem q;    /* q stores the q_elem structure */
```

Now, in the first case, to access structure's members you'll have to refer them by using `->` operator.

```
q_elem* q;
q->task;     /* access to def_task */
```

If you instead have a structure variable you can do:

```
q_elem q;
q.task;     /* access to def_task */
```

Inside your structure `q_elem`, `task` is defined as *a structure* and not as a *pointer to structure*. This means that once you have access to the `task` structure inside `q_elem`, accessing `task`'s fields is achieved by `.` (dot) operator.

This leave you with two choices:

```
q_elem* q;
q_elem->task.id
```

or

```
q_elem q;
q_elem.task.id
```

Notice the difference between the `q_elem` variable declaration.

I hope this explain things a little.

Comment: Thank you and everyone else who helped!